# Removing Items from an Array in Typescript Using .filter() - Immutable Pattern

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to remove item from array Using .filter() - Immutable Pattern

```
const drinks = ['Cola', 'Lemonade', 'Coffee', 'Water'];
const id = 'Coffee';
const idx = drinks.indexOf(id);
const removedDrink = drinks[idx];
const filteredDrinks = drinks.filter((drink, index) => drink !== idx);
```

But the problem I have that I have error like this

**const idx: number
This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'string' and 'number' have no overlap**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `.filter`'s callback, the first argument is the value being iterated over, and the second argument is the index being iterated over. TypeScript is correctly warning you that comparing the `idx` - a number - to one of the array elements - a string - doesn't make sense.

`indexOf` is completely superfluous anyway here. Just use

```
const drinks = ['Cola', 'Lemonade', 'Coffee', 'Water'];
const id = 'Coffee';
const filteredDrinks = drinks.filter(drink => drink !== id);
```